# Корзина с добавлением товара

Tags: битрикс, php

Добрый день.

Есть 1(3-4 торговых предложений) товар,  с детальной каталога отправляется нужное кол-во товара в корзину.
 В корзине инклюдами компонент корзина и одношаговое оформление.
 Собственно вопрос:

Как сделать добавление того же товара но с другими предложениями в самой "корзине"? Либо использовать другой компонент?

Второй день голову ломаю

Answer (score 1):

Можно только доработать шаблон компонента корзины (или сам компонент также)  и реализовать в нем соответствующий функционал с использованием php и api битрикс.

Для добавления в корзину рекомендую использовать высокоуровневую функцию [Add2BasketByProductID](http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/catalog/basket.php).